# Inserting data based on matching data

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I have two tables (which I import from Excel 2010 into mySQL database) with the following columns:

Table #1 **PlayerDetails**

```
Season | RoundNo | Surname | FirstName | Team
```

Table #2 **MatchDetails**

```
GameID | TeamID | Season | RoundNo | Team
```

The three common fields are `Season`, `RoundNo` and `Team`.

What I need to do is add two new columns in **PlayerDetails** called `GameID` and `TeamID`.  I have over 260,000 rows in **PlayerDetails** and I need to find a way of automatically populating these two new columns by passing the `GameID` and `TeamID` values from **MatchDetails** into the corresponding fields in **PlayerDetails** rather than manually entering the data.

I would therefore like **PlayerDetails** to have the following columns:

```
|GameID | TeamID | Season | RoundNo | Surname | FirstName | Team
```

I have no idea whether its best to do this in XL, XL VBA or run an insert query in MySQL. Nor do I know where to start.

I have tried this in SQL but the query doesn't work - my sql skills aren't the best.

> insert into PlayerDetails (GameID)
>       select GameID
>       from MatchDetails
>       where MatchDetails.Season=PlayerDetails.Season AND MatchDetails.RoundNo=PlayerDetails.RoundNo AND MatchDetails.Team=PlayerDetails.Team

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you writing to a MySQL table from Excel, then I assume you would find it acceptable to populate the fields in Excel first then export. You can use a simple `VLOOKUP` formula if you first create a composite key on the **MatchDetails** table using the `Season`, `RoundNo` and `Team` values. The formula would then be:

```
=VLOOKUP(C6&"-"&D6&"-"&G6,$A$10:$F$15,2,0)
```

Where:

- `C6&"-"&D6&"-"&G6` is the key in **PlayerDetails** that references the composite key in **MatchDetails**
- `$A$10:$F$15` is the data in **MatchDetails**

Picture might help:

[image]